# Remove last occurrence of string in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, raspberry-pi

There's a file called `/etc/rc.local` that ends with `exit 0`. I need to append some code onto the file, but the `exit 0` is preventing that code from executing.

Using `sed`, `awk` and/or `tac`, how can I remove only the last occurrence of `exit 0` so that more script can be appended onto the end of the file?

rc.local file before my script runs:

```
if [ -e /boot/disable_rc_setup.txt]; then
  exit 0
fi

if [ -e /boot/setup.txt]; then
  bash /home/pi/setup.sh
  rm /boot/setup.txt
fi

exit 0
```

Current rc.local after script runs:

```
if [ -e /boot/disable_rc_setup.txt]; then
  exit 0
fi

if [ -e /boot/setup.txt]; then
  bash /home/pi/setup.sh
  rm /boot/setup.txt
fi

exit 0

curl 192.168.1.5/online
if [ -e /boot/first_boot.txt]; then
  curl 192.168.1.5/first_boot
  rm /boot/first_boot.txt
fi

exit 0
```

You can see the `exit 0` above the initial curl command.

Desired Goal rc.local:

```
if [ -e /boot/disable_rc_setup.txt]; then
  exit 0
fi

if [ -e /boot/setup.txt]; then
  bash /home/pi/setup.sh
  rm /boot/setup.txt
fi

curl 192.168.1.5/online
if [ -e /boot/first_boot.txt]; then
  curl 192.168.1.5/first_boot
  rm /boot/first_boot.txt
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: I'd put your code before `exit 0`.

Comment: How to do that? It's a script writing to the file with `echo "CODE" >> /etc/rc.local`

Comment: you need to replace ALL non-commented occurrences of exit , like ```sed -i 's/\s*exit\s*.*//' /etc/rc.local```

Comment: There may be other code that may `exit 0` the file before getting to this code. They need to stay.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Cyrus added examples of current and desired output.

Comment: I suggest to remove `exit 0` before your script runs, if possible.

Comment: Yeah, that's what my question is, lol. How to do that with sed, awk and/or tac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of running `echo "CODE" >> /etc/rc.local`, try:

```
sed -i '/^exit 0/d' /etc/rc.local
echo "CODE" >> /etc/rc.local
```

Only the last line of code containing `exit 0` will be deleted, because there are no trailing blanks at the beginning. If you are not sure this will always be the case, adapt the code to be sure to delete only the last occurence of `exit 0`.

Comment: It's not exactly it, but it'll do! Not sure how sed works for only replacing the last occurrence, I'll give `sed -i '/^exit 0/d\1/' /etc/rc.local` a try.

Comment: @Slyke: Your file contains only **one** string that has no spaces in front and is `exit 0`.

Comment: @Slyke: No, don't put `d\1`, just `d`. This means: delete the line matching `exit 0` at the beginning of the line `^` and delete it `d`. I suggest you never to issue commands on system files just as a guess.

Comment: @Cyrus Yeah, but my question was how to replace the last occurrence of a string (`exit 0`). Technically that means spaces on the front could or couldn't be there. The file was for an example of what I mean to better communicate what I meant exactly. I'll just use `sed -e "$(grep -n 'exit 0' /etc/rc.local | cut -f1 -d: | tail -n 1)d" /etc/rc.local`.

Comment: @Slyke: Another way to match the last occurence of `exit 0`, without assuming the amount of blank space in front of it, is to issue: `sed -i '/exit 0/,$d' rc.local`. If several lines match the regex `/exit 0/`, the pair `/exit 0/,$` will only match the last block starting with `exit 0` that is ending with the last line `$`, and it will also delete the lines after `exit 0`, blank lines in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

*how to replace the last occurrence of a string `exit 0`* using awk. A bit changed `rc.local` with unwanted code after the last `exit 0`:

```
$ cat rc.local
if [ -e /boot/disable_rc_setup.txt]; then
  exit 0
fi

if [ -e /boot/setup.txt]; then
  bash /home/pi/setup.sh
  rm /boot/setup.txt
fi

exit 0

# unwanted code commented out with the above exit
```

The awk:

```
$ awk '{   
    a[NR]=$0                            # hash records to a index on NR
    if($0~/^ *exit +0 *$/ && NR==FNR)   # remember last exit 0 of the 1st file
        nope=NR
    if(NR==FNR)                         # also remember where the 1st file ended
        last=NR
}
END {
    for(i=1;i<nope;i++)                 # output upto last line before the exit
        print a[i]
    for(i=last+1;i<=NR;i++)             # then output the replacement 
        print a[i]
    for(i=nope;i<=last;i++)             # and from exit to the end of 1st file
        print a[i]
}' rc.local code_to_append
```

Output:

```
if [ -e /boot/disable_rc_setup.txt]; then
  exit 0
fi

if [ -e /boot/setup.txt]; then
  bash /home/pi/setup.sh
  rm /boot/setup.txt
fi

curl 192.168.1.5/online
if [ -e /boot/first_boot.txt]; then
  curl 192.168.1.5/first_boot
  rm /boot/first_boot.txt
fi
exit 0

# unwanted code commented out with the above exit
```